# HTML5 textbox/textarea clickable text

Tags: html

Good Day,

Can I know if it is possible/there exists a UIkit that allows certain text say those with # to be clickable?

For example:

## text# hello world inside a text area, populated by some php get script. I want #text# to be clickable and that should perform some action.

Comment: You mean like a hyperlink?

Comment: yes,something that allows me to click

Comment: do you want the content of the textarea to be clickable?

Comment: No, it is not possible for a textarea, but Konza gave you a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method by which you can make some part of the content of a textarea clickable.
Here we are not using a textarea. instead we use a div with contentEditable=true. Then we change the style of the div so that it looks like a text area. 
now with javascript you can replace the words inside the div with anchor tags..

```
<style type="text/css">
    #editableDiv {
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        background-color: white;
        background-color: -moz-field;
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;
        font: -moz-field;
        font: -webkit-small-control;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        width: 398px;
    }
</style>

<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this #text. <a href="www.google.com">click here</a>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Click here to change the content</button>
<script>
    function displayResult() {
        var x = document.getElementById("editableDiv").innerHTML;
        var m = x.replace("#text", "<a href ='#'>replaced text</a>");
        document.getElementById("editableDiv").innerHTML = m;
    }
</script>
```

In the above javascript code instead of #text you can use regular expressions also

Comment: Call me a fool. But I pretty much just started touching HTML yesterday. I only know the old HTML structure of things. Okay, so i have pasted this peice of code into my body of text and I see that the formatting has changed.

However, is it possible to say "POST" that into a link with some additional formatting?

Comment: Also, this won't work with textarea? What if I need to input multipe lines of code

Comment: I didnt get you. Could you please elaborate.